# How can I open a pdf file in project folder before and after release?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, pdf

I made a simple WinForms application in which I want to include a button that opens a pdf document using the default software for opening pdf in windows. I would like this to work running the app through visual studio (with or without debugger) as well as after release.

I would greatly appreciate the help as I've been stuck in this problem for a while.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I created a folder called "Resources" within the project folder and included the pdf document there.

Based on some things I read I attempted the following but did not work:

```
var pdfDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"Resources\MyPdfDocument.pdf";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfDirectory);
```

Also:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = pdfDirectory
};
proc.Start();
```

Also, instead of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location I also tried with Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() with no success either.

In the Solution Explorer, I also selected the pdf file and set these properties [Build Action > Content] and [Copy to Output Directory > Copy Always].

Most of my attempts have resulted in an error window that says
"An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users...\MyProject\Resources\MyPdfDocument.pdf' with working directory 'C:\Users...\MyProject\bin\Release\net6.0-windows' The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform." or similar.

Comment: `var pdfDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,  @"Resources\MyPdfDocument.pdf");` -- Create a new ProcessStartInfo, use the path as the `FileName`, set `UseShellExecute = true`, call `Start()` with that `ProcessStartInfo`

Comment: I attempted that too. Did not work either

Comment: That's what I can tell you (and what should work), which assumes you have added a Folder in Solution Explorer named `Resources` that points to the same folder of your executable -- Note that the exception you're mentioning doesn't match the code you have posted, because refers to two different paths. It appears you're trying to use the Resources folder that VS creates for the resources of your Project: this folder of course doesn't exist when you deploy, it's just related to the development of your app -- BTW, in your *second attempt* you forgot `UseShellExecute = true`

Comment: You're a life saver!!! I don't know how I missed that field, but you were right and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to [jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi?tab=profile) for providing the answer in the comments almost immediately and saving me a headache.

Using the following seems to work:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = pdfDirectory,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
proc.Start();
```

My previous attempts had failed because I was unaware that the UseShellExecute property must be set to true. Depending on the .NET version you're using, this might be already be true by default.